# What does "position: relative" actually mean?

Tags: html, css, position, w3c

`w3.org/TR/CSS2` [says](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details):

> For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box.

What does it mean? I read it as `position: relative` doesn't affect an element itself, but actually affects its parent - *the containing block*.

So, to change CSS of *the containing block* do I have to  apply `position` to its child?

Isn't it strange? There is a pattern when you apply `position: relative` to a parent, and `position: absolute` to some of its child to make that absolutely positioned child be tied to a parent.

Comment: afaik not necessarily, but since you are changing the way the child elements are positioned, the way the parent can compute its size (if that depends on the child elements) will also change.

Answer (score 1):

> ...actually affects its parent - the containing block.

The point of

> ... if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing
>   block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container
>   ancestor box.

is to explain that its parent is not necessarily its containing block.

Most notably, if it is `position:relative` and its parent is `display:inline`, then its parent is **not** its containing block, but an element further up the DOM tree is instead.

Answer (score 0):

position: relative means that the element which has been given a relative position will adjust itself relative to itself. For example:

An `h1` is given the following CSS:

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

then it will move 20px top and left from its original position. Check my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6sowku5/

Comment: I know that. That's why I'm asking a question. Why do they then say *the containing block [of positioned relative element] is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box*?

Comment: @Green: Why should the containing block have to change when position is relative? A relatively positioned box isn't going anywhere - any offsets are purely cosmetic and have no effect on layout (except, of course, that they may result in overflow).